# How to toggle comments in column 1 in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text-3

In Sublime Text 3, `Edit->Comment->Toggle Comment` (<kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> on a Mac) will comment out the current selection (or current line), or uncomment it, depending on its current state. It does this by inserting a space and the comment start character(s) at the start of the current line, in the column the current line starts in, preserving the leading whitespace. For example, commenting out the fourth line of this:

```
#***************************************************************************
sub invoke
{
    my($self) = @_;
```

would result in this:

```
#***************************************************************************
sub invoke
{
    # my($self) = @_;
```

I would really love it if it would left-justify the comment character, like this:

```
#***************************************************************************
sub invoke
{
#   my($self) = @_;
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Warning:

Doing this involves messing around with one of Sublime's core files. Don't continue if you're uncomfortable with that.

---

That being said, the changes you'll be making aren't that drastic, and are easily reversible. Don't worry, I'll make it easy.

The first thing you need to do is install [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) if you haven't already. Then, install [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer). Open the Command Palette, type ***`prv`*** to bring up the `PackageResourceViewer:` options, and choose `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`. Scroll down a bit, select `Default`, then scroll a little more and select `comment.py` to open the file in Sublime. You can now hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close the Command Palette. The first two function definitions look like so:

```py
import sublime, sublime_plugin

def advance_to_first_non_white_space_on_line(view, pt):
    while True:
        c = view.substr(pt)
        if c == " " or c == "\t":
            pt += 1
        else:
            break

    return pt

def has_non_white_space_on_line(view, pt):
    while True:
        c = view.substr(pt)
        if c == " " or c == "\t":
            pt += 1
        else:
            return c != "\n"
```

First, comment out all the lines of `advance_to_first_non_white_space_on_line()` except the final `return` statement:

```py
def advance_to_first_non_white_space_on_line(view, pt):
    # while True:
    #     c = view.substr(pt)
    #     if c == " " or c == "\t":
    #         pt += 1
    #     else:
    #         break

    return pt
```

Continuing on to `has_non_white_space_on_line()`, comment out *all* the lines:

```py
def has_non_white_space_on_line(view, pt):
    # while True:
    #     c = view.substr(pt)
    #     if c == " " or c == "\t":
    #         pt += 1
    #     else:
    #         return c != "\n"
```

Then, create a new line after the `return` statement, indent 4 spaces, and paste in the following:

```py
return view.substr(pt) != "\n"
```

making the whole thing look like so:

```py
def has_non_white_space_on_line(view, pt):
    # while True:
    #     c = view.substr(pt)
    #     if c == " " or c == "\t":
    #         pt += 1
    #     else:
    #         return c != "\n"
    return view.substr(pt) != "\n"
```

And that's it! Save the file, and just for fun try to comment out some lines in it - you'll see all the `#` comment characters are in column 1.

Now, this obviously will change the behavior for **all** languages, not just Python, so be prepared for that. To undo the changes, just replace the two function definitions with those in the first code block above. Oh, to get to the file again, you don't need to go through PackageResourceViewer. Instead, select **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** (or **`Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** if you're on OS X) to open the `Packages` folder in your operating system's file manager (Windows Explorer, Finder, Nautilus, etc.). In `Packages/Default` you'll find `comment.py`, just as you changed it. If you want to go back to the way things were before, just delete that file and you'll be all set (the original is stored elsewhere, but is overridden when an identically-named file exists in `Packages`).

If you're *really* adventurous, you can clone the file, rename it, and modify it to include logic to only indent like this with certain languages, but that's beyond the scope of this answer. Ask on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) if you want to know how to do that.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to Sublime -- is there a package-y way to override core functions like this?

Comment: @JoeCasadonte no, this is really the simplest way to do it. I suppose I could write a configurable plugin to do this, but it would be a non-trivial amount of work. If you *really* don't want to do this, let me know and I'll see what I can do, but the steps outlined here really represent the best way to override the current behavior without damaging anything - remember, the original file is still safe and sound (unlike if you'd be doing this in ST2), so you can delete your new `Packages/Default/comment.py` any time you want. If the instructions are somehow unclear, *please* let me know.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve for all languages without overriding any core commands, you can simply create a file called `disable_comment_indent.tmPreferences` (only the file extension is important, the base name itself isn't) in your `Packages/User/` folder (i.e. where `Packages` refers to the folder opened when you go to the Preferences menu -> Browse Packages) with the following content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>scope</key>
  <string>source</string>
  <key>settings</key>
  <dict>
    <key>shellVariables</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
          <key>name</key>
          <string>TM_COMMENT_DISABLE_INDENT</string>
          <key>value</key>
          <string>yes</string>
      </dict>
    </array>
  </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I no longer use Sublime, but hopefully this can help someone else -- thank you!